# Deleting DiagnosticConsumer in FrontendAction results in segfault

Tags: c++, initialization, clang, llvm, destructor

I'm writing a tool based on the clang front-end.
Here's my replacement for th `DiagnosticConsumer` and the FrontendAction.
Running this results in a segfault. If I just remove `delete BDCProto;` from the FrontendAction, it wont result in a segfault.
I'm confused. Why can't I just delete an object I created inside a class in the class dtor? I'm not playing funny with the scopes. Nobody is trying to use that pointer after the dtor, right?
What am I doing wrong?

```
class BlankDiagConsumer : public clang::DiagnosticConsumer
{
  BlankDiagConsumer() = default;
  virtual ~BlankDiagConsumer();
  virtual void HandleDiagnostic(DiagnosticsEngine::Level, const Diagnostic &Info) override {}
};



class LiveActionListVars : public ASTFrontendAction
{
  public:
    LiveActionListVars() {}
    ~LiveActionListVars() 
    {
      delete BDCProto;
    }

    void EndSourceFileAction() override {}

    std::unique_ptr<ASTConsumer> CreateASTConsumer(CompilerInstance &CI, StringRef file) override
    {
      DiagnosticsEngine &DE = CI.getPreprocessor().getDiagnostics();
      DE.setClient(BDCProto);
      TheRewriter.setSourceMgr(CI.getSourceManager(), CI.getLangOpts());
      return llvm::make_unique<LiveListVarsConsumer>(TheRewriter);
    }

  private:
    Rewriter TheRewriter;
    BlankDiagConsumer* BDCProto = new BlankDiagConsumer;
};
```

Comment: Does your code even compile? `BlankDiagConsumer` has no public constructors. Was that a copy-paste error? What does `DE.setClient(BDCProto)` do internally? The problem seems to be related to the `CreateASTConsumer()` function, as that is the only function shown that modifies `BDCProto`.

Comment: yes, that was a copy-paste error. `DE.setClient(BDCProto)` sets the my `DiagnosticCosumer` as the one the front-end will use.

Comment: it's not letting me edit my comment so here it is:yes. that was a copy-paste error. thanks for the help. I didn't bother to look at the signature. your question made me look at it. `setClient` has a second argument, `setClient (DiagnosticConsumer *client, bool ShouldOwnClient=true)` which explains why calling `delete` would cause a segfault. it's fixed now. My object was outliving the lifespan I conceived it had.

Comment: Glad your problem is solved. For future reference, please provide a minimal compilable example with all of the necessary code. This will help you get answers a lot faster.